# icu4j: read and write files with differenz charsets

Tags: java, character-encoding, icu4j

i am using java to parse a folder, and read the files. In the folder are only txt-files. But with different charsets. Some of them are in ISO-8859-1 and some of them are in windows-1252.

I need to read the file and create one single file from all. So i append the content. See my code:

```
File fiout = new File("single_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".csv");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fiout);
for( int x=0; x < all_zipEntries.size(); x++ ){
    File fi = (File)all_zipEntries.get( x );
    String zipfilename = fi.getName();
                
    String charset = getCharset(fi);
    Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName(charset);
                    
    log.println("Read "+zipfilename+" ... (Charset "+charset+" ... "+inputCharset.toString()+")");
                    
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fi.getName());
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, inputCharset);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    while ( in.ready() ) {
        String row = in.readLine(); 
        writer.println(row);
    }
    in.close();
    isr.close();
    fis.close();
}
writer.close();
```

This is my log:

```
Read 01.csv ... (Charset ISO-8859-1 ... ISO-8859-1)
Read 02.csv ... (Charset ISO-8859-1 ... ISO-8859-1)
Read 03.csv ... (Charset windows-1252 ... windows-1252)
Read 04.csv ... (Charset windows-1252 ... windows-1252)
Read 05.csv ... (Charset windows-1252 ... windows-1252)
Read 06.csv ... (Charset windows-1252 ... windows-1252)
Read 07.csv ... (Charset windows-1252 ... windows-1252)
Read 08.csv ... (Charset windows-1252 ... windows-1252)
Read 09.csv ... (Charset windows-1252 ... windows-1252)
```

You see the first 2 files are ISO coded, the last are windows-1252

My default charset is ISO-8859-1. In the result file that was createt by the code above i have some lines with

```
Äpfel
Äpfel
Äpfel
```

and i have lines like

```
?pfel
?pfel
```

The last one are from the files 3 till 9.
It seems to me he did not convert from windows-1252 to ISO correctly. But i set the charset at reading!

Comment: But, you're writing to 'fiout' with a ```Writer```  that is using the *system default* character encoding. So *how* are you viewing those files? It might be useful to know what that is, so: ```System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));```

Comment: So, what you *should* probably be doing is standardizing by writing to *one* output encoding that can encompass the various encodings that you've been reading. That output encoding should probably be UTF-8, so you need to *write* using that encoding

Comment: charset: ISO-8859-1
file.encoding: ISO-8859-1

Comment: I like to write to ISO-8859-1 all cheracters i need are available. I am viewing the file with the notepad. In the first line the characters will display correctly in later lines there is a ? instad of a Ä

Comment: Well then you must set that encoding on the output. It would be safer though to use UTF-8

Comment: How can i set it on the output?

Comment: With [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream,java.lang.String))

Comment: I try this: OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fiout.getName());
     OutputStreamWriter writerout = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); But it will write ?pfel instead of Äpfel in the file too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248673/discussion-between-g00se-and-mike).